# Deleting answers to questions that have been flagged as inappropriate for SO

Tags: discussion, answers

If one answers a question that is later closed or put on hold as it does no meet the standards of SO, should he/she delete the answer or let it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question is closed but you feel your answer is still helpful then you don't need (probably shouldn't) delete the answer. But this is entirely up to you.

From time to time, the criteria for an acceptable question on SO may change. So, a question which was acceptable two years ago may be off-topic by current standards. This does not mean that any answer on that closed question will not be helpful to others. Also, just because a question is closed/put on hold does not necessarily mean that it can't be reopend (we even have a queue for that).